# Time Stamp Filename plus File extension

Tags: php, file, file-upload, timestamp, file-extension

I am creating an upload script for images and have a working script although its a mess.

I am looking to see if there is a simpler way to streamline the method I am using to create a timestamped file name.

This is the code I have:

```
$mkfilename = time() . end(explode(".", strtolower($_FILES['pic']['name'])));
```

This is the most streamlined function I have been able to come up with so far, its just ugly on the function front. I'm sure there's a better way to do it.

Comment: what's so bad about it? seems quite simple

Comment: I just felt it needed a little less function after function and more 1 function does it all. I spose for a 1 liner its not bad though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much to improve:

> $mkfilename = time() . [strrchr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php)(strtolower($_FILES['pic']['name']), '.');

Not relevant for your question, but keep in mind that using only time() will conflict when two files are uploaded in the same second. Maybe you want to use like a hash function over time and filename.

Comment: in this case the upload would nearly be impossible to create an overwriting timestamp as I am using directory per person with single file upload.